# .NET MVC3 - Folders Within /Content Folder Missing When Publishing WebSite

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, publish

I have a folder in my /Content folder which is not being included when I build and publish my website. Only the standard CSS, Images, Scripts and themes folders have been included. I also have a Downloads folder containing .doc files that has not been included.

Am I limited to the standard set at the level below /Content?

Comment: Do the folders which aren't included contain any files? Empty folder aren't included in a build/publish.

Comment: @Robin Yes they do have files in them

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Empty folders typically don't get deployed.

For the Downloads folder, what's the "Build Action" set to for the items that it contains? They should be set to "Content" for anything that you want deployed. This isn't automatically set for some file types, such as PDF, etc.

The only items that get deployed have to be both referenced in the project (that is, they have to appear in the solution explorer, not just present in the folder on disk)
, and have the correct build action set.

[image]

You might also set the "Copy To Output Directory" setting to True and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks, never thought to look in there. I thought they would automatically be set to be included once I had set "Include in Project"

Comment: That's a rational assumption. Took me a good hour to figure this one out when I encountered it awhile back.

Answer (score 4):

In Visual Studio, right click on every folder underneath `/Content` folder, and choose *Include In Project*. Else, the files are only physically there on disk but the project doesn't *know* they are there and doesn't publish them.

Comment: Both the Downloads folder and the files inside have been set to "Include In Project".

Comment: OK... Have you checked what @David Lively suggested?